# Overloading a constructor to handle different data types

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I have a class with the following constructor

```
//matrix constructor
mat::mat(int nrows,int ncols){
  this->nrows=nrows;
  this->ncols=ncols;
  this->dat=new float *[nrows];
  for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++){
    this->dat[i]=new float[ncols];
     for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++){
        this->dat[i][j]=-9999;
      }
   }
}
```

as you see the constructor is for a matrix which contains floats. I would like to sometimes use the same constructor to create a matrix of integers. How can i do this with minimal change to the above code? i don't want to create a new class for the matrices to contain integers.

Thanks

Comment: i am a bit of a novice using template. Could you demonstrate please

Comment: Did so, see my answer ...

Comment: BTW, I suggest to avoid `new` and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I would also use vector<vector<T>> instead of many "new[]". If any new operator will throw exception (because, for example, ncols will be too big), you will have memory leak. With vectors you will avoid that. And there will not need to think about releasing memory. And there will be much less of code.

Comment: @Arkady A plain `vector<T>` might be a better option, for data locality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a templated mat class:

```
template<typename T>
class mat {
    //matrix constructor
    mat(int nrows,int ncols) {
        this->nrows=nrows;
        this->ncols=ncols;
        this->dat=new T *[nrows];
                   // ^ 
        for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        this->dat[i]=new T[ncols];
                      // ^ 
        for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++){
            this->dat[i][j]=-9999;
      }
   }
};
```

Replace every occurrence of `float` with `T`, and put all the code inlined in your `mat.h` header file.

**UPDATE:**

> how would the above code look with std::vector?

```
template<typename T>
class mat {
    //matrix constructor
    mat(int nrows_,int ncols_)
    : nrows(nrows_) , ncols(ncols_) {
        dat.resize(nrows);
        for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++) {
            dat[i].resize(ncols);
            for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++) {
                dat[i][j]=-9999;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> dat;
};
```

Comment: How would you declare an object of this class in another class when nrows and ncols are not yet known!!

Comment: @jjunju `mat<double> m_;`!!

Comment: @Jarod42 how would the above code look with std::vector?

Comment: `//matrix constructor
    mat(int nrows,int ncols) {
        this->nrows=nrows;
        this->ncols=ncols;
        //this->dat=new T *[nrows];
        vector< vector<T> > dat;//empty 2D-matrix of size (0,0).
        dat.resize( ncols , vector<T>(nrows , -9999 ) ); //resize & initilaise
        /*for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++){
            this->dat[i]=new T[ncols];
            for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++){this->dat[i][j]=-9999;}
        }*/
    };`

Comment: @jjunju [one of several ways](http://ideone.com/nYEa6W) to do it with `std::vector<>`